# JAX RS - Set incoming request Content Type to JSON

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jackson, jax-rs

In a JAX RS application, we can use `@Consumes("application/json")` to consume JSON data. But, if there is no `Content-Type` set, these web services fail with `NotSupportedException`. How do we tell a J2EE application to consider HTTP Requests with no `Content-Type` as HTTP Requests with `Content-Type` as `application/json`?

**EDIT**

I am using Jackson as the JSON Serializer. I did bring up a custom Servlet Filter to change any Content-Type to "application/json", but it is not somehow being recognized by JAX RS.

Comment: Not an answer but I would find which class throws NotSupportedException from stacktrace, then I would write my custom implementation by overriding related method, then tell to the context use my implementation

Comment: Well, I am looking for a solution to set the Content Type of an HTTP Servlet Request to "application/json" and then the JSON serializer would automatically pick up and deserialize it for me.

Comment: So what about adding a custom filter that you can modify request header

Comment: You mean using request wrappers? I have tried that, the serializers dont get triggered, unless I am doing it wrong.

Comment: I found small examle here http://thegreyblog.blogspot.de/2009/07/java-ee-filters-example-reading-http.html

Comment: @HRgiger Servlet filter is not working for this case. I tried. We need to find some other way to deal this. Jersey is not really calling `getHeader` method.

Comment: @aksappy according to Jersey implementation, we need to set content type so that corresponding method will be invoked. If you need to achieve everything just with URL. I would suggest you to use Jetty handler. You can check in this https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

Comment: Well, I think both Jersey and Resteasy does not allow this mechanism. Only reason I can think of is that the design to check and manipulate content type will become super flawed.

Comment: @Pasupathi - Not an option for a full fledged J2EE application. Thanks for the link, I have put it on pocket to read.

Comment: according to this existing question, the implementation should actually still pick a handler method if no content-type is set: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606639/jersey-consumes-doesnt-quite-work-when-content-type-is-not-set . Are you sure no content-type is set? This seems more like behavior when an unsupported content-type is set.

Comment: @Gimby Content-Type is not set. I have filters to check the enumeration of request headers. I am using POSTMAN to test this out and no Content-Type is being sent.

Comment: Fair enough; I would add the HTTP header log to the question as it is a relevant bit of proof.