# Handling mismatching Content-Type in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I keep getting errors of the form:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

So I attempted to defend against this error, as below:

```
@Path("auth")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class Auth {

@POST
@Path("login")
@Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
public Response create()
{
    return Response.status(Status.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE).build();
}

@POST
@Path("login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response create(@Valid @NotNull @FormParam("username") final String username,
        @Valid @NotNull @FormParam("password") final String password)
{
```

However, this doesn't prevent the problem. The FINE log messages generated are very spammy.

I have two questions:

1. Why isn't the more generic method invoked when the Content-Type is empty?
2. How can I prevent the actual method being invoked, when it does not match its @Consumes, to avoid log spam?

The environment is running Grizzly 2.3.28, Jersey 2.25.1, MOXy 2.7.1

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606639/jersey-consumes-doesnt-quite-work-when-content-type-is-not-set, if the Content-Type is NOT set by the client Jersey does NOT default but allows it to pass through any/all Consumes annotations. Is using different Path a viable solution in your case?

Comment: @yoav-gur. It's a form upload (on the Internet), the issue is, if someone does a POST to the path with random contents. I guess in production I will just adjust the log level to be above FINE and ignore it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could get that to work if you make a custom annotation to validate the content type and only accept `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`

You can use a `ContainerRequestFilter` that will read the headers and return 400 bad request if the `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` content type is not present.

Declare the annotation interface

```
@NameBinding
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface ContentTypeFilterAnnotation {}
```

Implement it as a `ContainerRequestFilter`

```
@Provider
@ContentTypeFilterAnnotation
public class ContentTypeFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    MultivaluedMap<String,String> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
    List<String> contentType = headers.get(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
    // if MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED is not present in the content type header, return a 400
    if(contentType == null || !contentType.contains(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)) {
      // build your error as you want it
      Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.serverError();
      Response response = responseBuilder.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
      requestContext.abortWith(response);
    }
  }
}
```

Then apply it to your endpoint

```
@POST
@Path("login")
@ContentTypeFilterAnnotation
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response create(@Valid @NotNull @FormParam("username") final String username,
                       @Valid @NotNull @FormParam("password") final String password) {
    ...
}
```

This should prevent Jersey from trying to get the form params if the content type is not as `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`.

Comment: You almost certainly _don't_ want to use the `@PreMatching` annotation in this case. If you specify it, the filter will apply to _all_ your endpoints. See, e.g., https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/PreMatching.html . Just remove the `@PreMatching` annotation from the definition of `ContentTypeFilter`, and the filter will then only be applied to the endpoints annotated with the `@ContentTypeFilterAnnotation` annotation.

Comment: @RichardWalker Fair point, not sure why I put it in there to start with. I'll remove it